# Mapping Java Objects from a SQL Query that joins two tables and uses Apache Ignite SqlFieldsQuery

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I am trying to map the result returned from a SQL Query that joins two tables in Apache Ignite into a Java POJO. As an example, let's say I have a table called `Person` with the below schema.

Table **Person**

Columns:

- id
- userName
- fullName

Table **Contact**

- id
- phoneNumber
- streetAddress

I am using the [SqlFieldsQuery](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/query/SqlFieldsQuery.html) to query the cache like below

```
String sqlQuery = "select a.id, a.userName, a.fullName, b.phoneNumber, b.streetAddress from person a join contact b";

List<Map<String, String>> finalResults = new ArrayList<>();
SqlFieldsQuery fieldsQuery = new SqlFieldsQuery(sqlQuery ).setTimeout(DEFAULT_QUERY_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

try (FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = getCache().query(fieldsQuery)) {
  for (List<?> row : cursor) {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
      result.put(cursor.getFieldName(i), Objects.isNull(row.get(i)) ? "(null)" : StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(row.get(i).toString()));
    }
  finalResults.add(result);
  }
}
```

Now I have a `List` of `Map` with each row being an entry in the `List`, and the keys in the`Map` being the column names and value being the column value.

I have a class called `personAggregate` that combines the columns from the two tables and need to map the results back to this class.

I want to avoid using mapper methods because this is a simple example but my equivalent `PersonAggregate` class has lot of fields.

I explored the option of using Jackson to create a POJO from `Map` but the `getFieldName` method of cursor always returns the column names capitalized.

Wondering if there is something inbuilt in Ignite cache query methods that I can use!

Thanks for the help in advance!